# Problema para obtener el cardinal de un conjunto de enteros

Tags: java

No consigo llegar a una solución para este problema puesto que al 
implementar el código que he desarrollado me devuelve que el cardinal del 
array {1,5,9,5,8,1,3,3,8} es 8 cuando en realidad debería de ser 5. Muchas 
gracias de antemano a todo aquel me ofrezca su ayuda para resolver este problema. Los arreglos serán de tamaño 10 siempre y el conjunto de enteros también. Además el conjunto de enteros no puede tener elementos repetidos.

```
public class ConjuntoDeEnteros {

    private int cardinal;
    private int [] elementos;
    public ConjuntoDeEnteros(){
        elementos = new int[10];
        cardinal =0;
    }
    public ConjuntoDeEnteros(int [] array) {
        elementos = new int[10];
        cardinal = 0;

        cardinal = array.length;                    //en el conjunto de enteros no habran elementos repetidos asi que si se le pasa un array {1,5,9,5,8,1,3,3,8} array.length = 9
        elementos = array;                          //el conjunto de enteros seria {1,3,5,8,9} y en vez de cardinal = array.length, el cardinal = 5
}
    public int cardinal () {
        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length;i++) { //el array siempre tendra 10 elementos pero puede no estar completo
            if(elementos[i] != 0) {                 //en este caso el cardinal sera igual al numero de elementos que haya en el array
                cardinal = i;                       //el cardinal se ira aumentando a medida que se vayan añadiendo los elementos al conjunto de enteros
            }else {
                cardinal = 0;
            }
        }
        return cardinal;
    }
}
```

Comment: No se mucho sobre cardinales y estoy seguro que muchos mas aqui tambien. Puedes explicar la operación que intentas realizar para obtener el cardinal?

Comment: Lo que intento es desarrollar un método que devuelva un entero y que ese entero refleje el número de elementos que tiene el conjunto de enteros.

Comment: @Daniel Checa la respuesta que puse, debe solucionar tu problema. Si no, déjame saber para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @skw ya lo probé pero no me funcionó

Comment: @Daniel Qué raro, a mí sí me dio exactamente 5, con el input que pusiste. ¿En qué parte pusiste el `Set`?

Comment: @Daniel Te pondré toda la clase para que la cheques.

Comment: @skw lo puse en donde los atributos

Comment: de todas maneras, seria posible hacerlo con variables en vez de tener que usar el setter?

Comment: @Daniel Respondiendo tu pregunta, sí sí sería posible, pero no muy práctico, por que tendrías que saber qué elementos ya tienes guardados. Dos preguntas, ¿tienes algún impedimento para usar el `Set` (trabajo de escuela, por ejemplo)? ¿El arreglo de entrada tendrá un conjunto de números específico, por ejemplo, solamente tendrá números del 1 al 9, pero no contendrá 7462?

Comment: @skw es un trabajo para la universidad y no puedo usar el set porque todavia ni lo hemos dado. Y a tu segunda pregunta puede contener cualquier tipo de numero entero siempre y cuando el numero de elementos del conjunto de enteros no supere los 10 elementos. Y los elementos del conjunto no se pueden repetir.

Comment: @Daniel, ¡¡Ah, ok!! Por ahí hubiéramos empezado, jajaja. Dame tiempo y te vuelvo a ayudar. Una sugerencia, para la otra, esa información ponla en la pregunta para que obtengas una respuesta más ad hoc a lo que necesitas.

Comment: @skw muchas gracias por tu respuesta. En el método cardinal tendría que hacer cardinal = this.cardinal y return cardinal y ya estaria no?

Comment: @Daniel, no, el método cardinal nada más necesitaría `return cardinal;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta todo lo que ya platicamos, eliminé mi respuesta anterior y ahora tengo esta nueva respuesta.

El problema es que lo que estás tomando como cardinal es el número de elementos que tienes en tu arreglo, pero lo que tú quieres es ***el número de elementos que no están repetidos***.

Ibas por buen camino desde un inicio. Te pongo el constructor que es donde está la lógica completa:

```
public ConjuntoDeEnteros(final int[] array) {
    // Inicializa el arreglo de elementos
    elementos = new int[10];
    // Variable que nos ayudará para saber si el número ya existe en nuestro arreglo.
    boolean existe;
    // Recorre el arreglo de entrada
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Obten el siguiente número de tu entrada
        final int num = array[i];
        // Resetea nuestra bandera
        existe = false;
        // Recorre el arreglo final
        for (int j = 0; j < cardinal; j++) {
            // Si el número que estamos evaluando
            if (elementos[j] == num) {
                existe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Si no se encontró el número entonces agrégalo a nuestro arreglo final y aumenta el cardinal.
        if (!existe) {
            elementos[cardinal] = num;
            cardinal++;
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto deberá ser suficiente para que puedas terminar tu trabajo. Lo que falta son cosas que ya tenías en tu código.

Déjame saber si te sirve esto. Intenté usar elementos que supongo ya deberías saber o que te habrán enseñado.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta eso lo tendria que cambiar por lo que yo tengo puesto en mi constructor con un parámetro verdad?

Comment: Sí, pero puedes jugar con los atributos, por ejemplo, no hay necesidad de tener `elementos` como variable de instancia, puedes tenerla como variable local. La cosa es que no sé qué más vas a hacer en esta clase, por ende lo hice más parecido a lo que tenías originalmente. Otra cosa, por ejemplo, no necesitas el constructor sin parámetros, ya que no tienes manera de agregarle los elementos así como está tu clase, ¿me explico?

Comment: si pero si quiero crear un conjunto vacía se crea con el constructor sin parámetros pero si lo quiero con elementos se crearía con el constructor con parámetros verdad?

Comment: @Daniel, así es, por eso te digo que no sé qué más vas a hacer con tu clase. En ese caso necesitarías un método `setter` (algo así como `setElementos(int[] arreglo)`) para agregarle ponerle elementos nuevos a tu arreglo. Vas por muy buen camino.

Comment: @Daniel, otra cosa, para que no te confundas, intenta nombrar tus métodos de manera distinta a tus variables, por ejemplo `getCardinal()`. Eso es estándar de nombramiento (naming convention) en Java.

Comment: lo del nombre cardinal lo puse porque el ejercicio me lo pedía así

Comment: vale y una ultima cosa. El problema ahora es que cuando se crea un conjunto vacio. En vez de crearlo como { } lo hace como si todos sus elementos fuesen 0 de esta forma: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} entonces como podría solucionar eso?

Comment: @Daniel No puedes crear un arreglo de enteros vacíos, como tú bien lo dijiste, un número siempre tiene que ser un número. Cuando no inicializas un número, Java automáticamente le pone cero. De cualquier manera, eso no te debe afectar. Si lo que quieres es enviar un arreglo de cero elementos, puedes hacerlo así `int[] arreglo = new int[0];`

Comment: es que cuando lo ejecuto me dice eso "No devuelve los elementos que debe devolver para un objeto creado pasándole {1, 5, 9, 5, 8, 1, 3, 3, 8} al constructor. Debe dar {1, 5, 9, 8, 3} y da {1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}"

Comment: ¿Cuando ejecutas qué? Me parece que estás utilizando JUnit, ¿correcto? En ese caso no pusiste todo el código en tu pregunta original, por que ningún método que pusiste devuelve el arreglo.

Comment: puse solo la parte que me daba problemas porque sino se hacía mucho código

Comment: @Daniel Ah, ok, ok. Mira, te recomiendo entonces que abras otra pregunta para no mezclar temas ni respuestas. Ábrela y el día de mañana lo revisaré para ver de qué se trata pues mi día está a punto de terminar y si alguien no te ha ayudado le echaré un ojo para ver en qué te puedo ayudar.

Comment: vale! muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.